# handling German characters

Tags: c#, asp.net, localization

I am building a page to manage files uploaded to the server.

Some customers have uploaded files with filenames containing obscure German characters.
The system can't seem to read these properly, although it has no problem with Chinese characters!

Filename1: `1--Referenz Frau Strauß.docx`

What the system sees: `1--Referenz Frau Strau&#223;.docx`

Here is my code:

```
protected void gvFiles_RowDeleting(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Button btn = (Button)sender;
    GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)btn.NamingContainer;

    TableCell cell = row.Cells[0];
    string fName = cell.Text;
    cell = row.Cells[1];
    string owner = cell.Text;
    if (owner == "-")
    {
        string filePath = "";
        filePath = getFilePath();
        string path = filePath + fName;
        if (File.Exists(path))
        {
            File.Delete(path);
        }
    }
    postbackProc();
}
```

The field in question is cell.Text. It is displaying on screen correctly, but does not find the file.

I am getting the filenames from the server:

```
private void GetFilesFromDirectory(string DirPath)
{
    try
    {
        DirectoryInfo Dir = new DirectoryInfo(DirPath);
        //Label1.Visible = true;
        lblPath.Visible = true;
        lblPath.Text = DirPath;
        FileInfo[] FileList = Dir.GetFiles("*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories );
        DataTable dt = new DataTable("File_List");
        DataRow dr;
        int iRow = 0;
        dt.Columns.Add("refFileName", typeof(String));
        dt.Columns.Add("Owner", typeof(String));
        foreach (FileInfo FI in FileList )
            {
                iRow++;
                dr = dt.NewRow();
                dr["refFileName"] = FI.Name;
                dr["Owner"] = getFileData(FI.Name);
                dt.Rows.Add(dr);           
            }
        gvFiles.DataSource = dt.DefaultView;
        gvFiles.DataBind();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
}
```

Any solutions?

Comment: Get rid of that try/catch block. All it will do is mess up your stack trace.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: These are not _obscure_ german characters BTW...

Answer (score 1):

I can only imagine you having problems with utf-8

Make sure that your all your server-side files (.aspx, .ascx, .html, .cshtml ..etc) are all with (save as, with encoding, utf-8 ..with or without bom)

Also check your web.config for correct utf handling

```
<system.web>
    <globalization requestEncoding="utf-8" responseEncoding="utf-8" responseHeaderEncoding="utf-8" fileEncoding="utf-8" />
</system.web>
```

Comment: Added that line to web.config. It made no difference. Still reads it wrong. I can't do anything about the file names - the files are already there!

Comment: That does NOT answer my question. Put it another way. String fName contains &#223; I want it to have ß. How do I convert it?

Comment: it should not contain &#223; ..that's html entities (htmlEncode/decode)

Comment: Thanks, Robert - that worked. Wrapped the string in Server.HTMLEncode().

Comment: Np, still you should try and figure why it's getting converted to htmlEntities in the first place, when running in full utf-8 everything should be just plain characters.